# Phonegap APP testing in chrome + ripple

Tags: cordova, device

I'm trying to understand why something very simple is not functioning. It does work on my android, but not in Chrome with ripple.

When I build a new Phonegap project, add `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />` to the config.xml, and in the deviceready

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {

    alert(device.uuid);
    console.log(device.uuid);
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined

I also tried to add the plugin with '**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device**', without luck.

What am I missing? I googled for the past 2 hours, but can't find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you call it before the device is actually ready. As mentioned [here](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/device-is-not-defined/)

for example, you could try something like this:

```
phoneui.documentreadyhandler = function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            alert(device.uuid);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was calling it within the deviceready, but thanks!

The workaround for me, but it's not an answer to my question
`
if (typeof device === "undefined"){
   device_id = 'unknown';
}else{
   device_id = device.uuid;
}`